# Optimizing max Collatz sequence

Tags: erlang

I'm looking to optimize my solution for the maximum Collatz sequence problem in Erlang. Right now I've tried using ETS, and the following solution uses maps, but I'm getting worse performance than I feel I should. Is there perhaps some optimization I could do to improve it?

```
-module(collatzMaps).

-export([start/2, s/4]).

collatz(0, Map) -> 
    {0, Map};
collatz(M, Map) ->

    Exists = maps:is_key(M, Map),
    case Exists of    
        false ->

            case M rem 2 == 0 of
                true ->
                    Result = collatz(M div 2, Map),
                    Val = (1 + element(1, Result)),
                    Map1 = maps:put(M, Val, element(2, Result)),
                    {maps:get(M, Map1), Map1};

                false ->
                    Result = collatz((3 * M + 1), Map),
                    Val = (1 + element(1, Result)),
                    Map2 = maps:put(M, Val, element(2, Result)),
                    {maps:get(M, Map2), Map2}
            end;
        true ->

            {maps:get(M, Map), Map}
    end.

s(N, M, Max, Map) ->

    if
        N =< M ->

            Result = collatz(N, Map),
            if
                element(1, Result) > Max ->
                    NextMax = element(1, Result),
                    MapNext = element(2, Result),
                    s(N + 1, M, NextMax, MapNext);
                true ->
                    MapNext = element(2, Result),
                    s(N + 1, M, Max, MapNext)
            end;
        true ->
            Max
    end.

start(N, M)->

    statistics(runtime),
    statistics(wall_clock),
    Map = maps:new(),
    Map1 = maps:put(1, 1, Map),
    G = s(N, M, 0, Map1),
    {_, Time2} = statistics(wall_clock),
    U2 = Time2 / 1000,
    io:format("~p seconds~n", [U2]),
    G.
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, first let's tweak up invocation which will allow us to make some simple statistics and compare different approaches

```
-export([start/2, max_collatz/2]).

...

max_collatz(N, M) ->
    Map = maps:new(),
    Map1 = maps:put(1, 1, Map),
    s(N, M, 0, Map1).

start(N, M)->
    {T, Result} = timer:tc( fun() ->  max_collatz(N, M) end),
    io:format("~p seconds~n", [T / 1000000]),
    Result.
```

So let's write it more Erlang idiomatic way

```
-module(collatz).

-export([start/2, max_collatz/2]).

collatz_next(N) when N rem 2 =:= 0 ->
    N div 2;
collatz_next(N) ->
    3 * N + 1.

collatz_length(N, Map) ->
    case Map of
        #{N := L} -> {L, Map};
        _ ->
            {L, Map2} = collatz_length(collatz_next(N), Map),
            {L + 1, Map2#{N => L + 1}}
    end.

max_collatz(N, M) ->
    Map = lists:foldl(fun(X, Map) -> {_, Map2} = collatz_length(X, Map), Map2 end,
                      #{1 => 1}, lists:seq(N, M)),
    lists:max(maps:values(Map)).

start(N, M) ->
    {T, Result} = timer:tc(fun() -> max_collatz(N, M) end),
    io:format("~p seconds~n", [T / 1000000]),
    Result.
```

Then we can compare speed using for example [eministat](https://github.com/jlouis/eministat).

Clone in

```sh
git clone https://github.com/jlouis/eministat.git
cd eministat
make
```

If you run in a problem like

```
 DEPEND eministat.d
 ERLC   eministat.erl eministat_analysis.erl eministat_ds.erl eministat_plot.erl eministat_report.erl eministat_resample.erl eministat_ts.erl
compile: warnings being treated as errors
src/eministat_resample.erl:8: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
erlang.mk:4940: recipe for target 'ebin/eministat.app' failed
make[1]: *** [ebin/eministat.app] Error 1
erlang.mk:4758: recipe for target 'app' failed
make: *** [app] Error 2
```

You can fix it

```diff
diff --git src/eministat_resample.erl src/eministat_resample.erl
index 1adf401..0887b2c 100644
--- src/eministat_resample.erl
+++ src/eministat_resample.erl
@@ -5,7 +5,7 @@
 -include("eministat.hrl").

 -export([resample/3, bootstrap_bca/3]).
--compile(export_all).
+-compile([nowarn_export_all, export_all]).

 %% @doc resample/3 is the main resampler of eministat
 %% @end
```

So then run it

```
$ erl -pa eministat/ebin/
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Eshell V10.1  (abort with ^G)
1> c(collatzMaps), c(collatz).                                                                                                                                  
{ok,collatz}
2> eministat:x(95.0, eministat:s(orig, fun() -> collatzMaps:max_collatz(1, 100000) end, 30), eministat:s(new, fun() -> collatz:max_collatz(1, 100000) end, 30)).
x orig
+ new
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|+    ++++++++ +++++   * +  +x+**+xxxx**x xxx xx+x xxx *x  x  +   x       x|
|        +   + +                   x x xx            x                     |
|        +                                                                 |
|                               |_______M___A__________|                   |
|      |________M_____A______________|                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Dataset: x N=30 CI=95.0000
Statistic     Value     [         Bias] (Bootstrapped LB‥UB)
Min:         1.76982e+5
1st Qu.      1.81610e+5
Median:      1.82954e+5
3rd Qu.      1.87030e+5
Max:         1.94944e+5
Average:     1.84280e+5 [      8.00350] (   1.82971e+5 ‥    1.85749e+5)
Std. Dev:       3999.87 [     -102.524] (      3128.74 ‥       5431.13)

Outliers: 0/0 = 0 (μ=1.84288e+5, σ=3897.35)
        Outlier variance:    3.22222e-2 (slight)

------

Dataset: + N=30 CI=95.0000
Statistic     Value     [         Bias] (Bootstrapped LB‥UB)
Min:         1.69179e+5
1st Qu.      1.72501e+5
Median:      1.74614e+5
3rd Qu.      1.79850e+5
Max:         1.90638e+5
Average:     1.76517e+5 [      3.11862] (   1.74847e+5 ‥    1.78679e+5)
Std. Dev:       5343.46 [     -147.802] (      4072.99 ‥       7072.53)

Outliers: 0/0 = 0 (μ=1.76520e+5, σ=5195.66)
        Outlier variance:    9.43164e-2 (slight)

Difference at 95.0% confidence
        -7762.60 ± 2439.69
        -4.21240% ± 1.32391%
        (Student's t, pooled s = 4719.72)
------

ok
```

So it seems like 4% faster now which is not much. First, we can inline `collatz_next/1` which is basically what you have in your `collatz/2` function. I like to be specific so I put between `-export` and a first function

```
-compile({inline, [collatz_next/1]}).
```

It have very little effect

```
Difference at 95.0% confidence
        -9895.27 ± 5524.91
        -5.24520% ± 2.92860%
        (Student's t, pooled s = 1.06882e+4)
```

Then we can try roll out `lists:fold/2`, `lists:seq/2` and `lists:max/1` as in your `s/4` function but let's do it more idiomatic way.

```
max_collatz(N, M) ->
    max_collatz(N, M, 1, #{1 => 1}).

max_collatz(M, M, Max, _) -> Max;
max_collatz(N, M, Max, Map) ->
    case collatz_length(N + 1, Map) of
        {L, Map2} when L > Max ->
            max_collatz(N + 1, M, L, Map2);
        {_, Map2} ->
            max_collatz(N + 1, M, Max, Map2)
    end.
```

Well it's better but still not much

```
Difference at 95.0% confidence
        -1.78775e+4 ± 1980.35
        -9.66832% ± 1.07099%
```

Now, when we removed all external code calls it's worth to try native compiling (external function call usually ruins any native compilation benefit). We could also add little type hint for HiPE but it seems to have barely any effect (it is usually worth to try for floating point arithmetic which is not this case and heavy usage of maps is probably issuing problem here as well).

```
max_collatz(N, M) when N < M, is_integer(N), is_integer(M) ->
    max_collatz(N, M, 1, #{1 => 1}).
```

Not much better

```
c(collatz, [native]).
...
Difference at 95.0% confidence
        -2.26703e+4 ± 2651.32
        -12.1721% ± 1.42354%
        (Student's t, pooled s = 5129.13)
```

So its time try it dirty. Process dictionary is not the recommended place to store your data but if it is inside special process it is an acceptable solution.

```
collatz_length(N) ->
    case get(N) of
        undefined -> 
            L = collatz_length(collatz_next(N)),
            put(N, L + 1),
            L + 1;
        L -> L
    end.

max_collatz(N, M) when N < M, is_integer(N), is_integer(M) ->
    P = self(),
    W = spawn_link(fun() ->
                           put(1, 1),
                           P ! {self(), max_collatz(N, M, 1)}
                   end),
    receive {W, Max} -> Max end.

max_collatz(M, M, Max) -> Max;
max_collatz(N, M, Max) ->
    case collatz_length(N + 1) of
        L when L > Max ->
            max_collatz(N + 1, M, L);
        _ ->
            max_collatz(N + 1, M, Max)
    end.
```

Yes, its dirty but working solution and its worth it (even without `native`)

```
Difference at 95.0% confidence
        -1.98173e+5 ± 5450.92
        -80.9384% ± 2.22628%
        (Student's t, pooled s = 1.05451e+4)
```

So here we are from 3.6s down to 0.93s using some dirty tricks but anyway, if you would do this sort of tasks, you would probably use NIF written in C. It is not a type of task where Erlang shine.

```
> collatzMaps:start(1, 1000000).
3.576669 seconds
525
> collatz:start(1, 1000000).                                                                                                                                   
0.931186 seconds
525
```